# function call with named/unnamed and variable arguments in python

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
def foo(func, *args, named_arg = None):
    return func(*args)
```

returning a `SyntaxError`:

```
  File "tester3.py", line 3
    def foo(func, *args, named_arg = None):
                                 ^
```

Why is that? And is it possible to define somewhat a function in that way, which takes one argument (`func`), then a list of variable arguments `args` before named arguments? If not, what are my possibilities?

Comment: Works in Python 3; this is how you define keyword-only arguments which cannot be passed positionally. This syntax isn't available in Python 2.

Comment: One of my first questions here is related to this : (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872824/calling-a-python-function-with-args-kwargs-and-optional-default-arguments)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The catch-all `*args` parameter *must* come after any explicit arguments:

```
def foo(func, named_arg=None, *args):
```

If you also add the catch-all `**kw` keywords parameter to a definition, then that *has* to come after the `*args` parameter:

```
def foo(func, named_arg=None, *args, **kw):
```

Mixing explicit keyword arguments and the catch-all `*args` argument does lead to unexpected behaviour; you cannot both use arbitrary positional arguments *and* explicitly name the keyword arguments you listed at the same time.

Any extra positionals beyond `func` are first used for `named_arg` which can also act as a positional argument:

```
>>> def foo(func, named_arg = None, *args):
...     print func, named_arg, args
... 
>>> foo(1, 2)
1 2 ()
>>> foo(1, named_arg=2)
1 2 ()
>>> foo(1, 3, named_arg=2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: foo() got multiple values for keyword argument 'named_arg'
>>> foo(1, 2, 3)
1 2 (3,)
```

This is because the any second positional argument to `foo()` will *always* be used for `named_arg`.

In Python 3, the `*args` parameter *can* be placed before the keyword arguments, but that has a *new* meaning. Normally, keyword parameters can be specified in the call signature as positional arguments (e.g. call your function as `foo(somefunc, 'argument')` would have `'argument'` assigned to `named_arg`). By placing `*args` or a plain `*` in between the positional and the named arguments you exclude the named arguments from being used as positionals; calling `foo(somefunc, 'argument')` would raise an exception instead.

Comment: when I do it like that and define a function as follows `def func(text): print "Some text: ", text` and call it via `foo` as `foo(func,'world')` I get the error `TypeError: func() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`. And a call `foo(func, named_arg = 1, "world")` also does not work (`SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg`).

Answer (score 2):

No, Python 2 does not allow this syntax.

Your options are:

1) move the named arg to appear before `*args`:

```
def foo(func, named_arg = None, *args):
   ...
```

2) use `**kwargs`:

```
def foo(func, *args, **kwagrs):
   # extract named_arg from kwargs
   ...
```

3) upgrade to Python 3.

Comment: For (2) `named_arg = kwargs.get('named_arg', None)` is how to extract the named argument with a default value. This is likely the much better answer to the O.P. because solution (1) would confuse foo(f,bar) with foo(f,named_arg=bar).

Answer (score 1):

change the order of the arguments to this:

```
def foo(func, named_arg = None, *args):
    return func(*args)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, no:

Tutorial [section 4.7.2](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) says:

> In a function call, keyword arguments must follow positional
>   arguments.

...and [4.7.3 says](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) about 'Arbitrary argument lists':

> Before the variable number of arguments, zero or more normal
>   arguments may occur.

...so if you're going to use all three argument types, they need to be in the sequence

1. Positional args
2. Named args
3. variable/arbitrary args