# How do I combine known arguments and variable arguments to pass them to another function?

Tags: python, argument-passing

I saw the following SO posts on variable arguments in Python:

[What does ** (double star) and * (star) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters)
[function call with named/unnamed and variable arguments in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821877/function-call-with-named-unnamed-and-variable-arguments-in-python)
[Can a variable number of arguments be passed to a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919680/can-a-variable-number-of-arguments-be-passed-to-a-function)

None of them answered my question. So, here it goes:

I would like to define couple of functions:

```
def LogError(log_file, *args):
  print("USER ERROR:", ***NOT SURE ABOUT THIS PART***, file=log_file)

def LogWarning(log_file, *args):
  print("USER WARNING:", ***NOT SURE ABOUT THIS PART***, file=log_file)
```

I want to call them using:

```
error_file = open("somefile")
LogError(error_file, "Unable to find", username, "in the database.")

warning_file = open("somefile")
LogWarning(warning_file, arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

I want the call to `LogError` to be the equivalent of

```
print("USER ERROR:", "Unable to find", username, "in the database.", file=error_file)
```

and I want the call to `LogWarning` to be the equivalent of

```
print("USER WARNING:", arg1, arg2, arg3, file=warning_file)
```

What's the best way to accomplish that?

Comment: Since there are no other arguments to the call, `print("USER ERROR:", *args, file=log_file)`? (assuming Python 3)

Comment: @JeffMercado, I tried that. That is equivalent of `print("USER ERROR:", ["Unable to find", username, "in the database."], file=error_file)`.

Comment: The `*` is important. It will expand `args` as if the function was called with the items as individual arguments in their corresponding positions.

Comment: To get that `list` as an argument, you would have to do `print("USER ERROR:", list(args), file=error_file)`. I'm not sure what you're doing for `print("USER ERROR:", *args, file=error_file)` not to work, but I can't reproduce it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first link you have should provide the answer

```
def LogError(log_file, *args):
  print("USER ERROR:", *args, file=log_file)

def LogWarning(log_file, *args):
  print("USER WARNING:", *args, file=log_file)
```

That would expand the arguments as you want. But instead of crafting your own solution, you should take a look at [python's built in logging feature](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/logging.html) instead.

Comment: I must've done something strange while testing. I thought I had tried that and it didn't seem to work. It works now :)

Answer (score 0):

Just join them with a space, since that's the end result anyway:

```
print('USER ERROR: {}'.format(' '.join(*args)), file=error_file)
```

You really should be using the [logging module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html), which will make your life easier:

```
import logging

# Create a logger
log = logging.getLogger(__file__)

# Set the output for different log levels
# this is optional, you can write out all errors to the
# console and do many combinations, such as sending emails

warning_logger = logging.FileHandler('warnings.log')
warning_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

error_logger = logging.FileHandler('error.log')
error_logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

# Set the format of messages
# levelname will be WARNING or ERROR depending on the message
log_format = logging.Formatter('USER %(levelname)s: %(message)s')

# Set the formatters for the error loggers
warning_logger.setFormatter(log_format)
error_logger.setFormatter(log_format)

# Add the handlers to the master logger instance
log.addHandler(warning_logger)
log.addHandler(error_logger)

# Now all you need is

log.warn('This is a warning')
log.error('This is a error')
```

For more details check out the [logging module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) and for more recipes, the [logging module cookbook](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-cookbook) is worth a read.

Comment: While that may work in this specific case, it wouldn't work for function calls in general.