# Add Target Group to application listener (AWS CDK PYTHON)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have been trying to run this code unsuccessfully, i am using python and the AWS CDK:

```
        applicationTargetGroup = elbv2.ApplicationTargetGroup(self, 'ApplicationTargetGroup', 
                            target_type=elbv2.TargetType.IP,
                            target_group_name='stg-test',
                            protocol=elbv2.ApplicationProtocol.HTTP,
                            port=8080,
                            vpc=vpc,
                            health_check=elbv2.HealthCheck(path='/images/favicon.ico')
                            )

    httpsListener.add_target_groups('TargetGroups', 
                            applicationTargetGroup, 
                            host_header='host.domain.com', 
                            priority=107)
```

The error I get is the following:

> File "/home/user/workspace/test/cdk/pytest/pytest/pytest_stack.py", line 33, in **init**
> httpsListener.add_target_groups('TargetGroups', applicationTargetGroup)
> TypeError: add_target_groups() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

I dont understand what I am doing wrong as the documentation states is ok:

> add_target_groups(id, *, target_groups, conditions=None, host_header=None, path_pattern=None, path_patterns=None, priority=None)

[AWS DOCS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2/ApplicationListener.html#aws_cdk.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.ApplicationListener.add_target_groups)

thanks

Comment: Arguments after a `*` in the function signature are passed by keyword only. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15074848/7867968) for more clarification, or also [PEP-3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/)

Comment: so are you saying i should do it like this:

httpsListener.add_target_groups('TargetGroups', 
                            target_groups=applicationTargetGroup, 
                            host_header='host.domain.com', 
                            priority=107)

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs for [add_target_groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2/ApplicationListener.html#aws_cdk.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.ApplicationListener.add_target_groups) it tell that `applicationTargetGroup` is passed a [key word argument](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#positional-only-parameters) and a `list`:

```
    httpsListener.add_target_groups(
                  'TargetGroups', 
                  target_groups=[applicationTargetGroup],  
                  host_header='host.domain.com', 
                  priority=107)
```

Comment: i got a new error but i guess is unrelated. Thanks. ill accept as answer.
C.Nivs sorry i cant accept comments as answers :)

Comment: @ChopLabalagun No problem. Please feel free to make new question regarding the new issue.