# Default arguments with *args and **kwargs

Tags: python, python-2.7

In **Python 2.x** (I use 2.7), which is the proper way to use default arguments with `*args` and `**kwargs`?
I've found a question on SO related to this topic, but that is for **Python 3**:
[Calling a Python function with *args,**kwargs and optional / default arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872824/calling-a-python-function-with-args-kwargs-and-optional-default-arguments)

There, they say this method works:

```
def func(arg1, arg2, *args, opt_arg='def_val', **kwargs):
    #...
```

In 2.7, it results in a `SyntaxError`. Is there any recommended way to define such a function?
I got it working this way, but I'd guess there is a nicer solution.

```
def func(arg1, arg2, *args, **kwargs):
    opt_arg ='def_val'
    if kwargs.__contains__('opt_arg'):
        opt_arg = kwargs['opt_arg']
    #...
```

Comment: Still the most succinct explanation I've run across: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/01/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python/

Comment: *Never* explicitly call `__contains__`. Always use `in`: `'opt_arg' in kwargs`. (Even better: `kwargs.get('opt_arg', 'def_val')` as in mgilson's answer).

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Just put the default arguments before the `*args`:

```
def foo(a, b=3, *args, **kwargs):
```

Now, `b` will be explicitly set if you pass it as a keyword argument or the second positional argument.

Examples:

```
foo(x) # a=x, b=3, args=(), kwargs={}
foo(x, y) # a=x, b=y, args=(), kwargs={}
foo(x, b=y) # a=x, b=y, args=(), kwargs={}
foo(x, y, z, k) # a=x, b=y, args=(z, k), kwargs={}
foo(x, c=y, d=k) # a=x, b=3, args=(), kwargs={'c': y, 'd': k}
foo(x, c=y, b=z, d=k) # a=x, b=z, args=(), kwargs={'c': y, 'd': k}
```

Note that, in particular, `foo(x, y, b=z)` doesn't work because `b` is assigned by position in that case.

---

This code works in Python 3 too. Putting the default arg *after* `*args` in Python 3 makes it a "keyword-only" argument that can *only* be specified by name, not by position. If you want a keyword-only argument in Python 2, you can use @mgilson's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15302038/355230).

Comment: Yes, that's due to the ambiguity of `*args`. Your way is correct if you want a keyword-only argument.

Comment: Just got it answered in the comments above.
(What if I want to call the function with a different b, and also I want to add *args?)

Comment: Anyway, before asking, I tried this solution, but I also found it that only worked if after defining the opt_arg I use only kwargs.

Comment: @nneonneo: I got your examples, but this way still doesn't give us the freedom to specify default arguments and *args at the same time, like Python 3.x allows it, as explained in the link; does it?

Comment: You can't leave a default argument alone while also filling in `*args`, no. This is why the functionality was added to Python 3. Typically, default arguments in Python 2 are specified as something obvious like 0 or `None` so that they can be explicitly passed in.

Comment: Just FYI, this solution gives a warning in `pylint` saying: `keyword-arg-before-vararg`. To avoid this warning, you can instead do `def foo(a, *args, b=3, **kwargs):`. However this will mean you **always** need to pass the value of `b` as a keyword argument

Comment: more, `foo(x, y, z, k) # a=x, b=y, args=(z, k), kwargs={}` is ok but `foo(a=x, b=y, z, k)` will be error

Answer (score 63):

The syntax in the other question is python3.x only and specifies keyword only arguments.  It doesn't work on python2.x.

For python2.x, I would `pop` it out of kwargs:

```
def func(arg1, arg2, *args, **kwargs):
    opt_arg = kwargs.pop('opt_arg', 'def_val')
```

Comment: It also specifies *args, before the default argument.

Answer (score 24):

Similar approach to @yaccob, but clear and concise:

In **Python 3.5** or greater:

```
def foo(a, b=3, *args, **kwargs):
  defaultKwargs = { 'c': 10, 'd': 12 }
  kwargs = { **defaultKwargs, **kwargs }
  print(a, b, args, kwargs)
  
  # Do something    

foo(1) # 1 3 () {'c': 10, 'd': 12}
foo(1, d=5) # 1 3 () {'c': 10, 'd': 5}
foo(1, 2, 4, d=5) # 1 2 (4,) {'c': 10, 'd': 5}
```

Note: you can use
In **Python 2**

```
kwargs = merge_two_dicts(defaultKwargs, kwargs)
```

In **Python 3.5**

```
kwargs = { **defaultKwargs, **kwargs }
```

In **Python 3.9**

```
kwargs = defaultKwargs | kwargs  # NOTE: 3.9+ ONLY
```

Answer (score 6):

You could also use a decorator like this:

```
import functools
def default_kwargs(**defaultKwargs):
    def actual_decorator(fn):
        @functools.wraps(fn)
        def g(*args, **kwargs):
            defaultKwargs.update(kwargs)
            return fn(*args, **defaultKwargs)
        return g
    return actual_decorator
```

Then just do:

```
@default_kwargs(defaultVar1 = defaultValue 1, ...)
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    # Anything in here
```

For instance:

```
@default_kwargs(a=1)
def f(*args, **kwargs):
    print(kwargs['a']+ 1)

f() # Returns 2
f(3) # Returns 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Sticking quite close to your solution approach while trying to make it more generic and more compact I would suggest to consider something like this:

```
>>> def func(arg1, arg2, *args, **kwargs):
...     kwargs_with_defaults = dict({'opt_arg': 'def_val', 'opt_arg2': 'default2'}, **kwargs)
...     #...
...     return arg1, arg2, args, kwargs_with_defaults

>>> func('a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a5', x='foo', y='bar')
('a1', 'a2', ('a3', 'a5'), {'opt_arg2': 'default2', 'opt_arg': 'def_val', 'y': 'bar', 'x': 'foo'})

>>> func('a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a5', opt_arg='explicit_value', x='foo', y='bar')
('a1', 'a2', ('a3', 'a5'), {'opt_arg2': 'default2', 'opt_arg': 'explicit_value', 'y': 'bar', 'x': 'foo'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to handle with Python 2.x:

```
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    if 'kwarg-name' not in kwargs.keys():
        kwargs['kwarg-name'] = 'kwarg-name-default-value'
    return bar(*args, **kwargs)
```

This handles passing arbitrary `*args` to the underlying call unlike @nneonneo's answer.

Comment: This would be clearer if you used valid code, i.e. `'opt_arg'` instead of `< kwarg-name >` and `'def_val'` instead of `< kwarg-name-default-value >`

Answer (score 0):

This answer is an extension of what [Daniel Américo suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50107777/11136955).

This decorator assigns default kwarg values if they are not *strictly* defined.

```py
from functools import wraps

def force_kwargs(**defaultKwargs):
    def decorator(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def g(*args, **kwargs):
            new_args = {}
            new_kwargs = defaultKwargs
            varnames = f.__code__.co_varnames
            new_kwargs.update(kwargs)
            for k, v in defaultKwargs.items():
                if k in varnames:
                    i = varnames.index(k)
                    new_args[(i, k)] = new_kwargs.pop(k)
            # Insert new_args into the correct position of the args.
            full_args = list(args)
            for i, k in sorted(new_args.keys()):
                if i <= len(full_args):
                    full_args.insert(i, new_args.pop((i, k)))
                else:
                    break
            # re-insert the value as a key-value pair
            for (i, k), val in new_args.items():
                new_kwargs[k] = val
            return f(*tuple(full_args), **new_kwargs)
        return g
    return decorator
```

### Result

```py
@force_kwargs(c=7)
def f(a, b='B', c='C', d='D', *args, **kw):
    return a, b, c, d, args, kw
#                               a    b  c    d  args      kwargs
f('r')                      # 'r', 'B', 7, 'D',   (),         {}
f(1,2,3)                    #   1,   2, 7,   3,   (),         {}
f(1, 2, 3, b=3, c=9, f='F') #   1,   3, 9,   2, (3,), {'f': 'F'}
```

#### Variant

If you want to use the default values as written in the function definition, you could access the argument default values using `f.func_defaults`, which lists the default values. You would have to `zip` them with the end of the `f.__code__.varnames` to match these default values with the variable names.