# What is a better way to define a class' __init__ method with optional keyword arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want the class to do the same as the following:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.last_name = kwargs['last_name']
        except:
            pass
        try:
            self.first_name = kwargs['first_name']
        except:
            pass
        try:
            self.score = kwargs['score']
        except:
            pass
```

But this looks really sloppy to me. Is there a better way to define this **__init__** method? I would like all of the keyword arguments to remain optional.

Comment: You normally would want to set `self.score` to a default even if `kwargs['score']` isn't available. And *don't use a blanket `except`* (see [Why is "except: pass" a bad programming practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21553327)); at most use `except KeyError`, but you are hardcoding the names anyway, so why use `**kwargs` at all?

Comment: only 3 keyword args ? then `def __init__(self, last_name = Null, first_name = Null, score = Null):`

Comment: @BhargavRao you should post it as an answer (it's a very valid answer).

Comment: @BhargavRao: *Null*? What language are you confusing Python with here?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you only have 3 arguments, then Bhargav Rao's solution is more appropriate, but if you have a lot of potential arguments then try:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.last_name = kwargs.get('last_name')
        # .. etc.
```

`kwargs.get('xxx')` will return the `xxx` key if it exists, and return None if it doesn't. `.get` takes an optional second argument that is returned if `xxx` is not in `kwargs` (instead of `None`), e.g. to set the attribute to the empty string use `kwargs.get('xxx', "")`.

If you really want the attribute to be undefined if it isn't in the `kwargs`, then this will do it:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)
```

it would be surprising behavior so I would suggest not doing it this way.

Comment: I've added an initial sentence about applicability.

Comment: This approach is dangerous, and may override class methods when colliding with keywords in kwargs. Consider adding `__slots__` or some kind of validity of the keywords you want to assign, as described below by @martineau https://stackoverflow.com/a/27732607/4369617

Comment: @redlus that might be the intended semantics, i.e. class vars are defaults that can be overridden by `__init__` arguments. If I wrote this today I would spell it as `self.__dict__.update(kw)` . We're all adults here, so this method is fine. If I wanted to introduce a limitation to only change existing vars I would insert a line before the `for`-loop:  `if len(self.__dict__) != len(set(kwargs) | set(self.__dict__)): raise ValueError('...')`.

Comment: @thebjorn you're right, but I meant a deeper effect than this. You can accidentally override a class method and get an exception. Here is a quick example: https://pastebin.com/GqyCycf2

Comment: @redlus well... don't do that then. Python is not a bdsm language, it let's you do many things that seem abhorrent to followers of such bdsm'ish languages(!)  E.g. you can assign to any instance variable (like `a.method = 'blah'`) -- and even more fun, you could instantiate Player as `p = Player(__class__=NotAPlayer)`, that's just Python being Python ;-)

Comment: @thebjorn lol on bdsming the language :)) If you're creating objects based on arbitrary input such defenses and assertions are necessary to prevent accidental mistakes which can take down the program. I'm all for having these defenses anyways :)

Answer (score 19):

If you have only only 3 keyword args, Then this would be better.

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self, last_name=None, first_name=None, score=None):
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.score = score
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's one way to do it that would make it easy to change:

```
class Player:
    _VALID_KEYWORDS = {'last_name', 'first_name', 'score'}

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for keyword, value in kwargs.items():
            if keyword in self._VALID_KEYWORDS:
                setattr(self, keyword, value)
            else:
                raise ValueError(
                    "Unknown keyword argument: {!r}".format(keyword))
```

Sample usage:

```
Player(last_name="George", attitude="snarky")
```

Results:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "keyword_checking.py", line 13, in <module>
    Player(last_name="George", attitude="snarky")
  File "keyword_checking.py", line 11, in __init__
    raise ValueError("Unknown keyword argument: {!r}".format(keyword))
ValueError: Unknown keyword argument: 'attitude'
```

Comment: Why not use `__slots__` if you're going this route?

Comment: @thebjorn: Premature optimization.

Comment: @thebjorn: … *and* because it has other side-effects plus there are several caveats to using them.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [**keyword arguments**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/):

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self, last_name=None, first_name=None, score=None):
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.score = score

obj = Player('Max', 'Jhon')
print obj.first_name, obj.last_name
```

```
Jhon Max
```

---

With arguments **[**kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301999/python-2-x-default-arguments-with-args-and-kwargs)**

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, **args):

        self.last_name = args.get('last_name')

        self.first_name = args.get('first_name')

        self.score = args.get('score', 0) # 0 is the default score.

obj = Player(first_name='Max', last_name='Jhon')

print obj.first_name, obj.last_name, obj.score
```

```
Max Jhon 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Can i try this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, val in kwargs.items():
            self.__dict__[key] = val

obj = Player(first_name='First', last_name='Last')
print obj.first_name
print obj.last_name

newobj = Player(first_name='First')
print newobj.first_name
```

Output:

```
First
Last
First
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the end result you want. If you want to create a class where the attributes are defined in the dictionary you can use setattr.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)             


In [1]: player = Player(first_name='john', last_name='wayne', score=100)

In [2]: player.first_name
Out[2]: 'john'

In [3]: player.last_name
Out[3]: 'wayne'

In [4]: player.score
Out[4]: 100

In [5]: player.address
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-0f7ee474d904> in <module>()
----> 1 player.address

AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'address'
```