# Ignore passed arguments

Tags: python, methods, arguments

Is it possible to ignore passed/overgiven arguments in a method?

Here is an example from something I want to do:

```
def event_handler(one, two):
   print(one)
   print(two)
```

And at another place:

```
event_handler(one, two, three)
```

I mean that the third argument is optional. I've tried in Python Fiddle, but it doesn't work without an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the third an default argument

```
def event_handler(one, two, third = None):
```

Then do error handling, but as it is default, it is easy.

```
def event_handler(one, two, third = None):
   print(one)
   print(two)
   if (three):
        print(three)
```

Comment: Yes, but is it possible to take that without setting a default for an argument?

Comment: AFAIK. You need to add a default value.

Comment: Ok, thank you for answering such a nooby question. ^^

Comment: Look up `*args` and `**kwargs`. They maybe of help to you

Comment: whats wrong with explicitly setting a default value? *args and **kwargs are better if you are overridding an existing method that you dont know the exact signature for

Comment: @Jonniboy You may wanna have a look at Joran's perfect explanation as to when to use def-args and when to use var-args.

Comment: And also take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732506/what-is-a-better-way-to-define-a-class-init-method-with-optional-keyword-ar/27732540#27732540) answer

Answer (score 2):

Use variable arguments with `*args`.

```
def f(*args): pass
```

Access the vars as a list like `args[0]`,...
Or,

```
def f(required_arg1, required_arg2, *optional_args): pass
```

Comment: the problem with this is it obscures the argument definition ... It is much better to use a default argument for this case imho ...