# Python Constructor Overloading

Tags: python, class

I have come across the notion of class constructors in C++. But I have not yet found a way to initialize a class in Python using 2 or more different methods. Could anyone tell how to go about that?

Comment: Look at `__init__` and `__new__` in the data model https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-e&q=python+init+vs+new. Usually in Python you don't implement the constructor (`__new__`) but just use `__init__` to initalise a new instance of your class.

Comment: Are you asking about constructors in general, or are you looking for an analog to C++'s overloaded constructors in Python?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html This is the standard way to go about constructors in general. Here is also a nice explanation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDa-Z5JzLYM. I hope this helps! :)

Comment: Python does not have method overloading if it is what you are looking for. But you can have different class methods acting like a factory, that is, with different names, accepting their own argument list and returning object instances of the same or different type.

Comment: @progmatico but that would not be like what __init__ provides, right? I don't want to create instances of car using methods car1 and car2.

Comment: No, but it is not so much different. For example, Instead of calling `c1 = Car(color="white")` you can call `Car.get_white_car()`. This does not create a new instance only to obtain another one from the method. Instead you create the instance as usual inside the method, which also runs init, and configure any additional or different settings there, then you return the instance. You can also process the init arguments or any additional arguments as you wish.

Comment: The method also works when called over an existing Car instance, but that is not as clear as it should.

Comment: Another approach is to capture the arguments for init in `*args` and `**kwargs` and process them accordingly, as mentioned in the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need multiple constructors in python, you can use the following way to initialize if you have multiple such a case

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, arg_1, arg_2=None):
        self.arg_1 = arg_1
        self.arg_2 = arg_2
```

So when you need to initialize an object of class A, you can use

```
a1 = A(2)
a2 = A(2, 4)
```

Though strictly speaking `__init__` is not a constructor but an initialiser

Comment: If it is a question of having a few optional arguments, of course this a valid choice. See `help(int.from_bytes)` for an example of what I meant in the comment above, giving an alternate method to `int()`

Answer (score 0):

@Ratan Rithwik solution is correct but only only 2 cases

If you want to have as many case as you want, you can use **kwarg
[one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27732506/what-is-a-better-way-to-define-a-class-init-method-with-optional-keyword-ar/27732540) with @thebjorn answer

EDIT: mixing 'standard' parameter (having default value) and kwargs

```py
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name='John', **kwargs):
        self.name = name
        self.last_name = kwargs.get('last_name')


p = Player(last_name='Doe')
print (p.name) # John
print (p.last_name) #Doe

p1 = Player('foo')
print (p1.name) # foo
print (p1.last_name) #None
```

Comment: Can I provide default values there somehow? Assume None might be a potential acceptable value

Comment: yes, you can use 'standard' parameter with default value : see my edit