# Function with args and default kwargs for Python 2.x and 3.x

Tags: python

I have a Python class with a method like:

```
class Table(object):
    def create_index(self, *fields, name=None):
        ...
```

which works fine in Python 3.4, but throws a `SyntaxError` in Python 2.7 because of the order of the args and default kwarg. If I change it to:

```
def create_index(self, name=None, *fields):
    ...
```

per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301999/python-2-x-default-arguments-with-args-and-kwargs) it works in Python 2.7 and does not throw an error in Python 3.4, however, `fields` always ends up being an empty tuple no matter what I pass in. I am calling it like:

`table.create_index('address')`

Is there some way to define a function with args and default kwargs that's compatible with both versions?

Comment: @wim, perhaps, what are the possibilities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly, in Python 2 you can't populate the `*args` whilst also omitting optional named arguments.  The feature you are using was added in Python 3, precisely for this purpose.

This is the best workaround I can think of:

```
def create_index(self, *fields, **kwargs):
    name = kwargs.pop('name', None)
```

It forces you to provide the `name` by name, but your original python 3 interface seems to have already required that anyway.