# py2 and py3 compatible code to replace extended unpacking (*args) in function

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, python-2to3, six

I have some python3 code that I'm trying to make compatible with python2.  This has mostly been easy using the `six` package and `__future__`, but I can't find a way around 'extended unpacking' (i.e. using the `*args` syntax).  For example, the function:

```
def func(a, *args, b=None, **kwargs):
    pass
```

What is the most elegant and/or simplest way to make this compatible with both python2 and python3?  Is there any solution in `six`, e.g. a wrapper or something?

While the question "[Default arguments with *args and **kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301999/default-arguments-with-args-and-kwargs)" is similar, it's solution is to use a *different* function instead of making the example one work (although, of course, that may be impossible).  i.e. `func(a, b=None, *args, **kwargs)` instead.

Since it raises a `SyntaxError` before execution a `try-except` won't work...

Comment: Basically impossible with this syntax, as Python 2 AST does not support this.  Closest way this can be done also in Python 2 is to manually pop `b` from `kwargs`.

Comment: @metatoaster if "basically impossible" means "impossible", then that seems like a complete answer

Comment: Which is what one of the answers in that linked question said.

Comment: Really though, it isn't _completely_ impossible, if dynamically modifying the input source file to generate a Python 2 compatible AST that satisfies the constraints are done (see: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39413170/2904896) for an idea how this might be done; but instead of writing back out the file, it would be compiled and added to `sys.modules`).