# How to use default arguments in a function call with *args and **kwargs?

Tags: python, function, default

I have the following simple example code:

```
def wrapper(foo, para1=1, *args):
    print("para1: "+ str(para1))
    print(foo(*args))

def foo1(x):
    return 2*x

wrapper(foo1, 2, 3)
```

where I define a function `wrapper` that has one parameter `para1` with default value `1`.

But in order to call the wrapper with function `foo1` correctly, I have to set `para1` all the time, because I have to pass the extra arguments to `foo1`. That means the default value `para1=1` does not make any sense, as I have to define it all the time anyway.

Or is there some other way to define the functions so I can easilz make use of this default value without to have to define it all the time?

For example,

```
wrapper(foo1, *args=(3,))
wrapper(foo=foo1, args=(3,))
```

does not work ...

**Use case example:**

```
def wrapper(foo, timeout=10, *args):
    time0 = time.time()
    while time0 < time.time() + timeout:
        if foo(*args):
             return True
        time.sleep(1)
    raise SomeTimeout Exception
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default arguments with \*args and \*\*kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301999/default-arguments-with-args-and-kwargs)

Comment: can't you put `para1` at the end of `wrapper` args?

Comment: No then I get a syntax error

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre then calls like `wrapper(foo1, 2, 3)` will break

Comment: I think that what you want is just impossible: too many constraints

Comment: That is correct. It is not being passed into foo1(). (e.g. a timeout parameter to check the completion of foo1() within some time etc.)

Comment: Is `foo1` always only taking a fixed number of param? perhaps you don't need to pass `*args` into `foo1()`?

Comment: The number of parameters can change. Its not a fixed number of parameters in `*args`.

Comment: Given `wrapper(foo1, 2, 3)`, how do you propose the interpreter to know the difference between this as a call of `foo1(2, 3)` or `foo1(3)`? I don't think there's any meaningful distinction unless you use a keyword to identify the param that's specific to `wrapper()`.

Comment: What is wrong again with `def wrapper(foo, *args, para1=1)`?

Comment: Which Python version are you using? Given your use of `print` it's Python 3?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I don't think there's anything wrong with it, unless OP is trying to stay away from keyword arguments (though it's stated as a possibility in the question title), in which case I just don't see a non-convoluted way of implementing unless there's a specific distinction between para1 and the `*args`.

Answer (score 0):

You defined the `foo1` function in a way that accepts a number, but you try to pass a tuple to it in the `wrapper` function.
the following should work:

```
def wrapper(foo, para1=1, *args):
    print("para1: "+ str(para1))
    print(foo(*args))



def foo1(*x):
    return 2*x


wrapper(foo1, (2, 3))
```

in the definition of `foo1` `x` changed to `*x`.

Comment: @Idlehands, It works! Maybe, the error comes from somewhere else.

Comment: It does not.  Have you actually tested it? `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` is what gets raised.  To be specific, `*args=...` is the source of the error.

Comment: @Idlehands, Yes I have! I updated my answer with complete code

Comment: With your latest edit, you're back to square one with OP.  What if you wanted to call wrapper without the `para1`? `wrapper(foo1, 3)` does not work.  The interpreter doesn't know the 2nd param does not exist.  `3` is the 2nd param in this case.

Comment: @Idlehands, alright. I got the question in a wrong way.  I updated the answer.

Comment: Please read the question carefully and test your answers.  None of your edits have achieved what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Since you have now made it clear it is for Python 2, `def wrapper(foo, *args, timeout=10)` would give you a syntax error.  So use the below method instead.

With just `*args` alone I don't think it's very feasible.  If possible, try making use of `**kwargs` instead:

```
def wrapper(foo, *args, **kwargs):
    time0 = time.time()
    # define a default timeout period if not explicitly passed in by keyword
    timeout = kwargs.get('timeout') if 'timeout' in kwargs else 10
    while time0 < time.time() + timeout:
        if foo(*args):
            return True
        time.sleep(1)
    raise SomeTimeOut Exception
```

Every time you want to explicitly provide a timeout period, call it as such:

```
wrapper(foo, 1, 2, 3, timeout=60)
```

## [Test code](https://repl.it/repls/MagentaFinancialServices):

```
def wrapper(foo, *args, **kwargs):
    timeout = kwargs.get('timeout') if 'timeout' in kwargs else 10
    print 'Timeout = {0}'.format(timeout)
    foo(*args)

def foo(*args):
    print 'Args = {0}'.format([a for a in args])

wrapper(foo, 1, 2, 3, timeout=20)

# Results
# Timeout = 20
# Args = [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: The second method at least should work for Python 2.  Please try again.

Answer (score 0):

What about making it like this?

```
#/usr/bin/env python3

def f1(f, *args, **kwargs):
    if not 'b' in kwargs:
        kwargs['b'] = 1
    print('b =',kwargs['b'])
    f(args)

def fx(args):
    print(args)

f1(fx, 3, 4)
print()
f1(fx, 3, 4, b=2)
```

Output:

```
b = 1                                                                     
(3, 4)

b = 2                                                                     
(3, 4)
```