# Python 3 best practice argument order

Tags: python

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872824/calling-a-python-function-with-args-kwargs-and-optional-default-arguments) it is described that since Python3 you can use this notation:

```
def func(a, b, *args, kw1=None, **kwargs)
```

to define a function, instead of traditional Python2 way:

```
def func(a, b, kw1=None, *args, **kwargs)
```

Is there any agreed best practice which signature should be used or is it based on personal preference?

Comment: [PEP-448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/) implemented in pyton 3.5.2 brings more changes

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There cannot be any "best" practice here, since those two definitions mean different (in a way, the opposite) things:

```
def func(a, b, kw1=None, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

means that the function will have an optional named argument `kw1`, which can be passed either as a keyword (`func(1, 2, kw1=3)`) or as an positional argument (`func(1, 2, 3)`). (In fact, unless specified explicitly with relatively new `/`-syntax, *any* named argument can be passed as a keyword.)

However, if a named arguments follows `*args` (or just `*`), it may be passed *only* as a keyword. For example:

```
def func(a, b, *, kw1=None, **kwargs):
    ...
```

cannot be called as `func(1, 2, 3)`, and having

```
def func(a, b, *args, kw1=None, **kwargs):
    print(a, b, kw1)
```

`func(1, 2, 3)` will print `1, 2, None`, because the positional argument goes to the `*args` part. (Thanks @tobias_k for pointing that out).

Comment: "cannot be called as func(1, 2, 3)" well, it can, but the `3` will go to `args`, not to `kw1`

Comment: you mixed up "keyword" and "positional" after the first code block

Comment: What kind of syntax is `func(a, b, *,...)`? Never saw that. Can you provide a reference?

Comment: @tobias_k it's [PEP 3102](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/)  (_'The second syntactical change is to allow the argument name to be omitted for a varargs argument.'_)