# How to make def x(*a, b=1) work on python2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, compatibility

`def x(*a, b=1)` is valid syntax on python3, but invalid on python2.

I know below work on python2

```
def x(*a, **kwargs):
    b=kwargs.get('b', 1)
```

But I just wonder if there any syntax patch can make python 2 compatible with `def x(*a, b=1)` ?
So that I don't need change all my code.

Comment: There isn't. Refer to [Python 3 best practice argument order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38169978/python-3-best-practice-argument-order) for why

Comment: @AdamSmith That won't work because `b` would then be considered the first positional argument.

Comment: @Adam Smith No, you can't .  If you do that,  first variable in list a would through into b

Comment: @blhsing eh true. Deleted