# How to return default values with *args, and **kwargs in function signature

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, args, keyword-argument

I'm trying to wrap my head around using `args` and `kwargs` in Python 3 (Python 3.7.0) but I'm running into some issues with my understanding.

Here is a simple function I have:

```
def add_args(y=10, *args, **kwargs):
    return y, args, kwargs
```

And test it to see what is returned:

```
    print(add_args(1, 5, 10, 20, 50))
    print(add_args())
    >>
    (1, (5, 10, 20, 50), {}) # What happened to my default y=10?
    (10, (), {})
```

What I don't understand is, what happened to `y=10` in the first print statement? I can see it is being overridden by the `1` in `args` but I'm unsure why.

How can I rewrite this function so the default value is not overridden, or am I missing something with how the parameters are passed from the function signature to the return statement?

I tried looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872824/calling-a-python-function-with-args-kwargs-and-optional-default-arguments) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301999/default-arguments-with-args-and-kwargs) but did not find the answers I was looking for. As I thought putting the default values before the `args` and `kwargs` would prevent the overwriting.

Comment: If you don't want it to be overridable by the caller, why is it a parameter at all? Why not just do `y=10` as the first line fo the body?

Comment: See my answer below, the accepted answer on the first link you checked does document this correctly: place `y=10` **after** the `*args` catch-all var-positional parameter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`*args` only captures any positional arguments not otherwise defined; `y=10` does not mean `y` can't be used as a positional argument. So `y` is assigned the first positional argument.

You can prevent `y` being used as a positional argument by making it a [*keyword-only* argument](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#keyword-only-parameter). You do this by placing the argument **after** the `*args` var-positional catch-all parameter, or if you don't have a `*name` parameter, after a `*` single asterisk:

```
def add_args(*args, y=10, **kwargs):
    return y, args, kwargs
```

or

```
def keyword_only_args(*, y=10, **kwargs):
    return y, kwargs
```

Now `y` won't capture positional arguments any more:

```
>>> def add_args(*args, y=10, **kwargs):
...     return y, args, kwargs
...
>>> add_args(1, 5, 10, 20, 50)
(10, (1, 5, 10, 20, 50), {})          # y is still 10
>>> add_args(1, 5, 10, 20, 50, y=42)  # setting y explicitly 
(42, (1, 5, 10, 20, 50), {})
```

You don't have to have a `**kwargs` keyword catch-all either:

```
def add_args(*args, y=10):
    return y, args
```

but if it is present, it needs to be listed last.

Keyword-only arguments do not have to have a default value, the `=10` can be omitted, but then the parameter becomes mandatory, and can only be specified in a call by using `y=value`:

```
>>> def add_args(*args, y):  # mandatory keyword-only argument
...     return y, args
...
>>> add_args(1, 5, 10, 20, 50)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: add_args() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'y'
>>> add_args(1, 5, 10, 20, 50, y=42)
(42, (1, 5, 10, 20, 50))
```

Comment: Ah thanks. I see where I went wrong. Great answer and I appreciate the response.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, `y` is the first positional argument in your function definition, so naturally it binds to the first actual positional argument at callsite, which is 1.