# How do you inherit methods from a class then add other arguments to it?

Tags: python

```py
class Parent():
    def foo(self, arg1):
        ...

class Child(Parent):
    def foo(self, arg1, arg2):
        ...
```

Linters (I'm using Pylint) complain about this piece of code because `Child().foo` has different arguments than `Parent().foo`

What's the correct method of doing this kind of thing?

Comment: How is this method supposed to be called?

Comment: The linters are complaining because this is considered bad practice, it breaks the Liskov Substitution Principle, that being said, you *can* do it and ignore your linter, but maybe you should stop and think about your overall design

Comment: You don't, generally, because that doesn't follow the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: @khelwood the method is supposed to be called on an instance, if it was a class method there would be a decorator

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga @jonrsharpe is it possible to add `*args` on both the `Parent` and `Child`'s `foo` methods?

Comment: @TNTzx ... right, but with how many arguments? If you have to know if it's Child or Parent so that you know the right number of arguments to pass, then it's not the same method, and it doesn't make sense to give it the same name as if it is an override.

Comment: @TNTzx you can do *whatever you want*. You are free to ignore your linter. I'm not sure what you are asking

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45523156/inheritance-change-signature-of-child-methods and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034662/python-method-overriding-does-signature-matter

Answer (score 1):

The correct way according to most would be to not alter the signature at all.  When you do it makes it harder to read and confusing if you need to make calls to `super` methods.

If you can't give the method a different name, then your next best option that would likely stop your linter from complaining is to have `*args` as the signature to both parent and child methods, and adjust the logic accordingly.

```py
class Parent:
   def foo(self, *args):
       ... do something

class Child(Parent):
    def foo(self, *args):
        arg1, arg2 = args
        ... do something
```

Comment: One can indicate that the arguments are unused by naming them `*_` (or perhaps more explicitly with `*unused`) in the parent definition of the method. Argument *names* do not have to match when a method is overridden in a subclasses.

Comment: This papers over the issue, you might as well just use a linter directive to actually ignore it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  If you tell the linter to ignore it then it won't detect any unintended occurrences of the same issue located elsewhere in the project.

Comment: @alexpdev pylint, and I imagine other linters, lets you ignore things on a line-by-line basis.