# Python linter warning: signature doesn't match base method

Tags: python

I'm subclassing a class that I made, and in the subclass I'm overriding a method of the parent class. For this particular method the linter complains about mismatch in signatures between this implementation and the implementation of the base method. In many other methods I don't see it complaining even though there's mismatch, what's the catch? and why is it good to match the signatures?

[image]

Comment: Could you also show the signature for the `evaluate` method in the `BaseModel` class you're inheriting from?

Comment: Please read [why an image of your code is not acceptable](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen this before too. Assuming you don't want them to match, e.g. you're extending the params the method takes, then you can just ignore or suppress this warning. I think it's there to try to warn you that you might have code that's incompatible but IMO it's not very helpful in most cases.

See also [Python Method overriding, does signature matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034662/python-method-overriding-does-signature-matter) for a decent explanation of why the warning might be useful.